# Split html by br, trim it and then add span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m trying to split lines by br tag, get the lines that start with a number and then wrap with span tags.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
        var swn = /^\d/;
        var lines = $('.caption').html().split(brExp).filter(line => swn.test(line.trim()));
        jQuery.each(lines, function() {
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
ROLLS:⠀<br>
   <li> ¼ cup warm water</li>⠀<br>
<li>1 tablespoon active dry yeast</li>⠀<br>
   <li> 2 ¼ cups sharp cheddar cheese, shredded⠀</li><br>
```

I’ve tried adding this line of code `this.text(jQuery(lines).wrap('<span itemprop="recipeIngredient"></span>'));` after console.log but it only gives an error that says cannot read property ‘ownerDocument’ of undefined.

Expected Output:

```
ROLLS:⠀<br>
<li><span itemprop="recipeIngredient">1 tablespoon active dry yeast</li><br>


<li><span itemprop="recipeIngredient">1 teaspoon sugar</span></li><br>

<li><span itemprop="recipeIngredient">2 ¼ cups sharp cheddar cheese, shredded</span></li><br>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: It is `$('#elem').html(jQuery(this).wrap('<span></span>')`.

Comment: @AjAX. Its still giving the same error

Comment: Can you give an example of the html and expected output?

Comment: @Samuel: please add the code part where you have `ownerDocument`...

Comment: @AndrewLohr Done. Please check again

Comment: @k.vincent I've edited it. Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regular expressions you can `.split("<br>");` on the html. This will push each piece between br tags into an array.

Then you can iterate through the array and see if the first char is a number. I used jQuery's [isNumeric](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) and also took into account your fraction characters by converting them to their ASCII code and comparing against that.

Next just create the span to house the new lines with the proper properties and inner text and then you're done.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  let a = $("#recipe").html().split("<br>");

  a.forEach(function(text) {
    if (text.trim().length === 0) return;

    let firstChar = text.trim()[0];

    // char codes are for fractions ½, ¼, ¾
    if ($.isNumeric(firstChar) || (firstChar.charCodeAt() >= 188 && firstChar.charCodeAt() <= 190)) {

      let $span = $('<span></span>').attr('itemprop', 'recipeIngredient').text(text);

      $("#result").append($span.prop('outerHTML') + "<br/>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recipe" class="hide">
  ROLLS:⠀<br> ¼ cup warm water⠀<br> 1 tablespoon active dry yeast⠀<br> 1 teaspoon sugar⠀<br> 1 cup milk⠀<br> 4 tablespoons butter, melted⠀<br> 1 egg, beaten⠀<br> 2 teaspoons salt⠀<br> 3 cups all-purpose flour⠀<br> 1 cup barbecue sauce⠀<br> 2 ¼ cups sharp
  cheddar cheese, shredded⠀<br> ½ cup green onions, chopped⠀<br>
</div>
<div id="result">ROLLS:<br/></div>
```

**Update**: For your question in the comment. If you wanted to use a list you can use jQuery to get all the li's and wrap them in a span before placing them in the result div

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  let a = $("#recipe li")

  a.each(function(index, elem) {
    let text = $(elem).text();
    if (text.trim().length === 0) return;

    let firstChar = text.trim()[0];

    // char codes are for fractions ½, ¼, ¾
    if ($.isNumeric(firstChar) || (firstChar.charCodeAt() >= 188 && firstChar.charCodeAt() <= 190)) {

      let $span = $('<span></span>').attr('itemprop', 'recipeIngredient').text(text);

      $("#result").append("<li>" + $span.prop('outerHTML') + "</li>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recipe" class="hide">
  ROLLS:⠀
  <ul>
    <li>¼ cup warm water⠀</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon active dry yeast⠀</li>
    <li>1 teaspoon sugar⠀</li>
    <li>1 cup milk⠀</li>
    <li>4 tablespoons butter, melted⠀</li>
    <li>1 egg, beaten⠀</li>
    <li>2 teaspoons salt⠀</li>
    <li>3 cups all-purpose flour⠀</li>
    <li>1 cup barbecue sauce⠀</li>
    <li>2 ¼ cups sharp cheddar cheese, shredded⠀</li>
    <li>½ cup green onions, chopped⠀</li>
</div>
<div>ROLLS:</div>
<ul id="result"> </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Nice idea creating a class hide. I was using regular expression because by tags tend to differ sometimes depending on the browser like </br> <br> <br />

Comment: no problem you can try experimenting with `.split("\n");` too which will split on a newline (no matter what <br/> version you use)

Comment: Hi, Andrew. Quick question, is there a way to get this to work even when first character is a number but in `<li>` Tag? Like maybe by using `innerText()` somewhere in the code.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example or your html? do you have your items in a list now?